# Plotting animation results in blank graph

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, graph

I have written this code and it will not plot. I run it with a `0:.5:100` and get a blank graph in Matlab. As well this is a inclined plane friction problem. I need to create an animation in Matlab that shows the blocks sliding based on inputs.

```
%Numerical Project Code 1

%mass ratio input
mratio = input('Enter the Mass Ratio(m/M): ');
%angle input
theta = input('Enter Angle in Degrees Between 0 and 90: ');
%static coeff input
mus = input('Enter Coefficient of Static Friction: ');
%kinetic coeff input
muk = input('Enter Coefficient of Kinetic Friction: ');

%constants
g = 9.81;

%interface formating
disp('--------------------------------------------');
disp('All Friction Forces are given in terms of the mass on the slope (M)');


%Loops
%NETUP

if mratio > sind(theta)
    %static only
    if mratio <= (sind(theta) + (mus*cosd(theta)))
        ff = g*(mratio - sind(theta));
        fprintf("Friction Force = %f M Newtons\n",ff);
        fprintf("The Direction of the Friction Force is down the slope and the block not moving.\n")




%kinetic only
else
    ff = muk * g * cosd(theta);
    fprintf("Friction Force = %f M Newtons\n",ff);
    fprintf("The Direction of the Friction Force is down the slope and the block is sliding up the slope.\n");


end



%NETDOWN

elseif mratio < sind(theta)
    %static only
    if sind(theta) <= (mratio + (mus*cosd(theta)))
        ff = g*(sind(theta) - mratio);
        fprintf("Friciton Force = %f M Newtons\n",ff);
        fprintf("The Direction of the Friction Force is up the slope and the block is not moving.\n")





%kinetic only
else 
    ff = muk * g * cosd(theta);
    fprintf("Friction Force = %f M Newtons\n",ff);
    fprintf("The Direction of the Friction Force is up the slope and the block is sliding down the slope.\n");


end


%NETZERO

else
    fprintf("Friction Force = 0 Newtons\n");



end
%graph
for i = 0:0.01:1


mratiog = i;

if mratiog  > sind(theta)

    if mratiog <= (sind(theta) + (mus*cosd(theta)))
        ffg = g*(mratiog - sind(theta));


   else 
        ffg =  muk * g * cosd(theta);


    end




elseif mratiog < sind(theta)

    if sind(theta) <= (mratiog + (mus*cosd(theta)))
        ffg = g*(sind(theta) - mratiog);

    else
        ffg = muk * g * cosd(theta);


   end



else
    ffg = 0;

end

  plot (ffg,mratio, 'r:')
end
```

Comment: Put a break point on the `plot` line and try to find out what the contents of `ffg` and `mratio` actually are just before plotting them. Also as a general tip: select all your code in MATLAB, right click it and auto-indent it for much better readability (at least here on Stack Overflow your code is badly indented).

Comment: And by the way, are you trying to plot scalars, i.e., `ffg` and `mratio` are `1x1` numbers? Then, nothing will be visible, because `plot` needs either 2 or more points to connect them with a line, or you need to specify a marker to make those single points visible. For example, try `plot(ffg, mratio, 'ro')` instead of `plot(ffg, mratio, 'r:')`. And use `figure, axes, hold on` before the for loop in which `plot` is called.

Comment: You can also take a look at [`animatedline`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline.html) to animate points being added to a graph in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Erik's comments I see two other issues:

- the plot changes its axis with each new iteration, so you can not see
  the animation properly. It would work better if you calculate all
  your points before plotting them. Then you can use min and max of data
  dimensions to set axis limits. If you don't use 'hold on' you need to set the limits in each iteration.
- you need to use 'pause' to slow down the
  animation. otherwise you see only the last data point.

Here is a working example of the 'graph' part:

```
%graph

i_arr = 0:0.01:1;
n = numel(i_arr);
ffg_mratio_arr = zeros(n, 2);

for i = 1:n
    mratiog = i_arr(i);

    if mratiog  > sind(theta)

        if mratiog <= (sind(theta) + (mus*cosd(theta)))
            ffg = g*(mratiog - sind(theta));
        else
            ffg =  muk * g * cosd(theta);
        end
    elseif mratiog < sind(theta)

        if sind(theta) <= (mratiog + (mus*cosd(theta)))
            ffg = g*(sind(theta) - mratiog);

        else
            ffg = muk * g * cosd(theta);
        end

    else
        ffg = 0;
    end

    ffg_mratio_arr(i,:) = [ffg mratio];
end

% calculating the axis limits
x_min = min(ffg_mratio_arr(:, 1))-1;
x_max = max(ffg_mratio_arr(:, 1))+1;

y_min = min(ffg_mratio_arr(:, 2))-1;
y_max = max(ffg_mratio_arr(:, 2))+1;

% animation
figure;

for i = 1:n
    plot (ffg_mratio_arr(i,1), ffg_mratio_arr(i,2), 'ro');

    xlim([x_min x_max]);
    ylim([y_min y_max]);

    pause(0.01);
end
```